# (Durrett : Probability : Theory and Examples ) Theorem 8.2.2

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, brownian-motion, martingales

I have some question on the proof of Theorem 8.2.2 from durrett's book.

In Theorem 8.2.2, Theorem 8.2.1 which is stated below is used.

> If $S_n$ is a sqaure integrable martingale with $S_0=0$,and $B_t$ is a Brownian motion, then there is a sequence of stopping times $0=T_0\leq T_1 \leq T_2\dots$ for the Brownian motion such that
> $$(S_0,S_1,\dots,S_k) \overset{d}{=} (B(T_0),B(T_1),\dots,B(T_k))$$

Theorem 8.2.2 is as follows,

> Let $\mathcal{F}_m = \sigma(S_0,S_1,\dots,S_m)$. $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} S_n$ exists and is finite on $\sum\limits_{m=1}^{\infty}E((S_m-S_{m-1})^2|\mathcal{F}_{m-1})<\infty$

The proof is, let $\mathcal{B}_t$ be the filtration generated by Brownian motion, and let $t_m = T_m - T_{m-1}$. Therefore, $E((S_m-S_{m-1})^2|\mathcal{F}_{m-1})=E(t_m|\mathcal{B}(T_{m-1}))$.

Let $M=\inf\{n:\sum\limits^{n+1}_{m=1}E(t_m|\mathcal{B}(T_{m-1}))>A\}$.

After some calculation we can get

$E\sum\limits^M_{t=1}t_m=E\sum\limits^M_{m=1}E(t_m|\mathcal{B}(T_{m-1}))\leq A$

From this it concludes that $\sum\limits^M_{m=1}t_m <\infty$, and as $A\rightarrow \infty$,$P(M<\infty)\downarrow 0$  ,so $T_{\infty}=\sum\limits^{\infty}_{m=1}t_m <\infty$.

The part I can't get is that how is $P(M<\infty)\downarrow$ related to $\sum\limits^{\infty}_{i=0}t_m$ ?Does $P(M<\infty)\downarrow$ means that $M\rightarrow \infty$ almost surely?

Comment: No, $P(M<∞)\downarrow\color{red}0$ means $\lim\limits_{A→∞}P(M<∞)=0$.

Comment: How are $S_n$'s related to BM? Not everyone  has a  copy of the book and you should give complete statement.

Comment: I updated the post!